# Creating an Azure API Connection via Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-logic-apps

I'm attempting to create an API Connection for use within a Logic App via Terraform. I see examples that have code like this:

```
data "azurerm_managed_api" "azuremonitorlogs" {
  name     = "${loca.prefix}-azuremonitorlogs"
  location = var.azure-region[local.workspace]
}

resource "azurerm_api_connection" "log_analysis_workspace" {
  name                = "${local.prefix}-availability-sli-log-conn"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  managed_api_id      = data.azurerm_managed_api.azuremonitorlogs.id
  display_name        = "Log Connection (${local.workspace})"
  parameter_values = {
    "token:clientId" : azuread_application.logaccess.object_id,
    "token:clientSecret" : azuread_application_password.logaccess.value,
    "token:TenantId" : data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id,
    "token:grantType" : "client_credentials"
  }
  lifecycle {
    # NOTE: since the connectionString is a secure value it's not returned from the API
    ignore_changes = [parameter_values]
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine except the `azurerm_managed_api` data source. I conceptually am not grasping what a "Managed API" is and no amount of searching nor digging through the Azure Portal is revealing where this Managed API comes from.

Since it is a data source only, I understand it needs to be created first. Is it possible to create it through an ARM template first by using `azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment`? Or does this somehow reference the predefined managed connections, such as the [Azure Monitor Logs connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuremonitorlogs/), in which case how does one determine which `name` to use in the data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it is not needed to create `azurerm_managed_api` first in the code. `Data` place can be placed anywhere in the code.

The purpose of the `azurerm_managed_api` data source to retrieve the ID of the managed API that you want to use in your `azurerm_api_connection` resource.

And coming to your question, managed APIs are often generated by Terraform or ARM templates, rather than being created directly in the Azure portal. Accordingly, the logic app will be able to interact with Azure Monitor Logs according to this managed API connection.

To create a Managed API, the template should include [`Microsoft.ApiManagement/service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template), [`apiVersionSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/apiversionsets?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template), [`service/apis`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/apis?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template). Using ARM template, you I tried creating an API Management service by referring to sample [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/quickstart-arm-template) and was able to deploy it successfully.

```bash
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
  },
  "parameters": {
    "apiManagementService": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "xxx"
      }
    },
    "publisherEmail": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "xxx"
      }
    },
    "publisherName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": ""
      }
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Developer",
        "Standard",
        "Premium"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": ""
      }
    },
    "skuCount": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1,
      "allowedValues": [
        1,
        2
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": ""
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location"
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
      "apiVersion": "2021-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('apiManagementService')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('sku')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('skuCount')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publisherEmail": "[parameters('publisherEmail')]",
        "publisherName": "[parameters('publisherName')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*Deployment succeeded:*

[image]

*Note:* If you're not sure which managed API to utilize, then refer to predefined managed connectors like [Azure Monitor Logs connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuremonitorlogs/).

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. I hadn't realized there were predefined managed api's. What I needed was the `azuremonitorlogs` managed API in the data source.